# PHP Doctrine - Failed to Perform Flush on 2 table in order

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm using Doctrine 2 and Symfony 2.7. It's working fine on my local machine, but on production it ran into weird issue.

I have a PHP script that create new User entity and then create new UserProfile entity for that user. But the UserProfile sometime is created and sometime not. It's getting worse that the rest of the script is stoped too.

Here is my code

```
$user = new Entity\User();
$user->setEmail(trim($data['email']));
$user->setName(trim($data['email']));
$user->setSalt($userManager->generateSalt());
$user->setPassword($data['encrypted_password']);
$em->persist($user);
$em->flush();

$profile = new Entity\UserProfile();
$profile->setIdUser($user->getId());
$profile->setIdDomain($themeHelper->getIdDomain());
$profile->setIsActive(true);
$profile->setIdAccountType($data['idAccountType']);
$em->persist($profile);
$em->flush();
```

Is there any chance that I have to wait for "$em->flush();" on User to complete, than continue execute the rest?

Many thanks.

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: This may or may not be related, but this doesn't seem necessary `$profile->setIdUser($user->getId());`, There should be a method called `->setUser($user)`.  Then after you've persisted both entities you should be able to call `->flush` just once, and doctrine will take care of mapping and correct insert order.

Comment: I got no error. Most of the time, this happen when end user sign up. I tried to look for error in Log files but no luck, also I tried to make it happen again by myself but It was working fine.

Comment: Dose the Flush method return anything? I read the docs but It seems like It's not.

Comment: Looking at your entity methods i think you need to work on your relationships between the two classes. You should not have to specifify the actual user id to the UserProfile class, instead create a doctrine relationship between the User and UserProfile entity. Look here: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html

Answer (score 0):

```
Try once :
After flushing the $user object first check the user record has been set properly and after checking it in 'if' condition like:
 if($user-> get Id())
{
$profile = new Entity\UserProfile();
$profile->setIdUser($user->getId());
$profile->setIdDomain($themeHelper->getIdDomain());
$profile->setIsActive(true);
$profile->setIdAccountType($data['idAccountType']);
$em->persist($profile);
$em->flush();
}
may be this will work and if not you would be able to know where it is creating problem
```